# having gradle problem when running flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

i need to do flutter project and submit it by next month to college and im still stuck in ground zero. i installed android studio and tried to run my project on physical device but always after some minute i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1308)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

i tried deleting my .gradle file in users floder and then run my project to let it reinstall .gradle, i did that 3 times but didnt lead to anything and i still face the problem. i also tried updating my flutter sdk. and for my last attempt i opened build.gradle in my flutter project and changing gradle version to 4.2.0 -> flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> flutter run but still the same problem

Comment: have you ran flutter doctor, if yes kindly share its output as well.

Answer (score 0):

create a new project
and try to run the default project 'with the addition number button' in your phone.

if still not working that mean the android studio or else are not configured correctly
recheck the tutorial:
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install
I am curious about your project so let me know your status, need help your are welcome

Comment: this is pretty stressful,dont know why my flutter doing this,i actually delete and reinstalled my android studio and trying my best going exactly how flutter doc said it.but i still get the same error.my flutter doctor is also all okay except for visual studio which i dont need since im making android app.also tried running it on visual studio code but nothing

Comment: open the app in the android emulator in debug mode and do dot in the code in the first page that load and look at problem 'console' with the default project, see if it work

Comment: thank you very much for the help,seem like the problem was with my gradle file.in that 3 time which android studio reinstalled them all of those times gradle file didnt get fully downloaded so i downloaded the gradle file myself and put it in .gradle and android studio successfully extracted it and now working

Comment: happy for you, nice done